# Scilab read wav file fails with error message

Tags: wav, scilab

I try to read a wav file with Scilab and try to plot waveform of the signals.

```
--> file = '/home/user/Documents/with1meg.wav'
--> [snd,Fs,bits]=wavread(file);Fs,bits
```

But it gives an error message like that :

> at line    70 of function wavread (
>   /usr/share/scilab/modules/sound/macros/wavread.sci line 85 )
>
> wavread: An error occurred: .wav file does not contain the RIFF
>   identifier.

Audacity opens wav file fine.

[image: Audacity wav file]

Wav file that I mentioned can be downloaded [here.](https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/F77/OYQH/GBBH8NXQ/F77OYQHGBBH8NXQ.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug related to Turkish locale. To fix the issue temporarily invoke scilab with this command.

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 ./scilab
```

In my system environment variables are like that :

```
$ locale
LANG=tr_TR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="tr_TR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Hello. I am quite interested by this issue, can you give a dump of your default environment variables related to localization (before the above fix), namely LANG, and LC_* (LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, ...)

Comment: I've added default environment variables. I suspect this might be a bug related to i letter. Because capital 'i' is 'I' in English but in Turkish capital 'i' is 'İ'. (Dotted I) Dotted İi and dotless Iı are separate letters in Turkish and Azeri Turkish.